# Mysql table update issues

Tags: mysql

I have created, inserted table values in database. I calculated Amount = Rate * Quantity.
But, last value is updated throughout the amount column in database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_product_details (ProductID, Rate, Quantity) VALUES ('$pid', '$rate', '$qty')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_product_details");
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=65%><tr><td>Product ID</td><td>Rate</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Amount</td></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
  $amt= $row['Rate']*$row['Quantity'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE wp_product_details SET Amount='$amt' where ProductID='$pid'");
  echo "<tr><td>".$row["ProductID"]."</td><td>" .$row['Rate']."</td><td>" .$row['Quantity']."</td><td>".$amt."</td></tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

ProdID  Rate   Qty      Amt
ABC10   120     3   280
XER45   150     3   280
YWE10   130     2   280
ZTW20   140     2   280

This is my output. Only last row value (Amount) is updated for all rows.
I need each row should update their own amount. Pls go through coding and help me.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE wp_product_details SET Amount = Rate * Quantity;`

You can use the WHERE clause if only specific product id's changed like so;

`UPDATE wp_product_details SET Amount = Rate * Quantity WHERE ProductID IN (0,3,5,7);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE wp_product_details SET Amount='$amt' where ProductID='$pid'");
```

Why do you need to call that multiple times ?

Comment: ABC10  120  3  280
XER45  150  3  280
YWE10  130  2  280
ZTW20  140  2  280

This is my output. Only last row value is updated for all rows

Comment: Do you have any other update query beside the code that you shows us ?

Comment: that's strange. I don't think you need to call the update. Just insert the value in the first place and you just need the while loop to print the value